# Redirect page to a page hosted on github

Tags: redirect, github, github-pages

I have page abc.com that i want to redirect to page fgh.com.  fgh.com is hosted on github pages (cname file has fgh.com, and navigating to fgh.com works).
I set up a redirect with the hosting service from abc.com to fgh.com but I get a 404 error. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you trace the redirection from the command line (e.g., using wget or curl)? Does the output still make sense (i.e. no change from http->HTTPS, no weird characters, etc)?

Comment: What kind of redirect did you use? HTTP 301? HTTP 302? DNS CNAME? Something else?

Comment: I used a 301 redirect

Comment: Do the 404 is on abc.com or on fgh.com ? What is your repository url ?